# Python-Jira installation without Admin rights

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am writing a python tool that should get information from Jira. I wanted to use Python-Jira but cannot install it properly. I am using (have to use) python 2.7 which doesn't come with pip and I cannot install pip because I do not have local admin rights (and won't get them without hassle).

Is there a way to install/use python-jira without the pip installation process? I tried copying the jira package to the site-packages folder but it seems I run into dependency problems ('ImportError: No module named six.moves' when I try import Jira from jira) which to resolve it seems I have to follow the pip installation process.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and you will have your own version of Python and Pip, so you should be able to install jira-python properly.

There is a lot of guides how to do it.

[For Linux I recommend this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu)

[General Python Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)